# Adding Javascript to a CMS Page

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I am adding a countdown timer to a single CMS page that is counting down to September 20th, 2015.

I put all the javascript functions in `js/countdownClock.js`

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if(t.total<=0){
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
}

var deadline = 'September 20 2015 08:59:59 UTC+0800';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Then I called the file in the CMS page under the Layout Update XML sections:

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addItem">
    <type>js</type><script>countdownClock.js</script>
  </action>
</reference>
```

In the Content section of the page I put in:

```
<div id="clockdiv">
<div><span class="days">.</span>
<div class="smalltext">Days</div>
</div>
<div><span class="hours">.</span>
<div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
</div>
<div><span class="minutes">.</span>
<div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
</div>
<div><span class="seconds">.</span>
<div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I load the page however, only the labels Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds displays. The javascript is supposed to calculate the time remaining and output the information in the content of the page with the span tags.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Is the page even calling the javascript correctly?

Comment: Using your browser's developer tools, do you see the JS file being loaded on that specific page? Also, do you see any errors, especially JS errors in the Console?

Comment: I do see "Failed to load resource" messages in the Console

Comment: Is `js/countdownClock.js` one of those resources? If it is, you should see a message indicating why the resource was blocked.

Comment: clear both browser cache and server cache

Comment: use your function inside `document ready`.

Comment: Adi - The only error associated with countdownClock.js is:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null"

Answer (score 1):

Because you're loading your javascript in the HEAD it's downloading the file and executing the code before the content exists on the page.  A simple solution can be found below which would execute your function once the page content was ready to be executed against.

Update the final line of countdownClock.js like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
});
```